# How to make input text file a constructor parameter? c++

Tags: c++, file, input, parameters, constructor

I'm trying to make input file, which is supposed to be chosen by a user, a constructor parameter. The problem is that my code is not working. My guess after some research is that type of parameter, that is *string fileName* may be wrong. I also tried to put *fstream fileName* but that didn't worked too. I'm looking forward to hear any advice how to make code work properly.
Here is code:

```
using namespace std;
class Parameters
{
public:
   Parameters( string fileName);
};
Parameters::Parameters(string fileName)
{           
    cout<< "Give name of the file:" << endl;
    cin >> fileName;
    fstream plik( fileName.c_str() );
    plik.open( fileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::out );

    if( plik.good() == true )
    {
        cout << "file is open" << endl;          
    } 
        else 
        cout << "error" << endl;    
    }

int main()
{
    Parameters s("");
    getch();
    return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: "_The problem is that my code is not working._" Such statement is useless information. Please elaborate on _how_ it is not working.

Comment: Do you mean to have the prompt for the filename in your main method and not your Parameters method ? As it stands the fileName parameter serves no purpose.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius when i run code and put name of the example file as an input, its not even opening.

Comment: @auburg I want the user to chose name of the file which will be parameter of constructor. Would you explain a little further why fileName parameter is useless?

Comment: Because it's not doing anything - you should have the prompt (cin >> filename) in your main method - what's the use of passing an empty string as you are doing now ?

Comment: My advice is: don't do this. I thought the same way a long time ago, and it still has some appeal, *but* it works a lot better with the rest of the standard library if you use `operator>>` to read your data. Trying to read it in the ctor ends up being kind of a pain to use.

Comment: @auburg its part of the code which have 3 constructors to initialize some parameters, in this case they will be taken from a file which is given by a user.

Comment: @JerryCoffin not sure if i understood you correctly. im going to read some data from input file, but it wasn't issue i had problem with.

Comment: @Uroboros: yes, my comment wasn't really directed to the problem you're having at the moment. It was just observing that (at least in my experience) the general approach you're taking doesn't really fit well with the rest of the standard library.

Comment: @JerryCoffin thanks for advice, im actually using ">>" to read data; what is this ctor you mentioned?

Comment: @Uroboros: `ctor` is a widely used abbreviation for `constructor` (likewise `dtor` for `destructor`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are openning the file twice:

1. `fstream plik( fileName.c_str() );`
2. `plik.open( fileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::out );`

you should change it to open only once, like:

```
fstream plik;
plik.open( fileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::out );
```

or:

```
fstream plik( fileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::out );
```

If the file still won't be openned you should check why.
You can print the error description using:

```
cout << "error: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
```